# I need the current position within onBindViewHolder on click using invoke

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to pass the clicked element to the calling activity in my RecyclerView in the onBindViewHolder method. There I need the just clicked element or the number. How do I do it?

```
class AddNewHomeFragment : Fragment() {

rv_img.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(),3)
   
    adapter = CustomerAdapter(requireContext(),listImg){

        //NEED CLICKED ITEM NUMBER HERE

        var intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(intent,IMAGE_REQUEST)
    }

 ... }
```

Adapter Class (CustomerAdapter):

```
class CustomerAdapter(val context: Context,
                  private val listImg:ArrayList<Bitmap>, private val onClickFunction: ((Any?) -> Unit)? = null):RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerAdapter.MyCustomViewHolder>() {

...

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyCustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.customImg.setImageBitmap(listImg[position])
    holder.customImg.setOnClickListener {
        this@CustomerAdapter.onClickFunction?.invoke(listImg[position])
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor should be:

```
class CustomerAdapter(val context: Context,
    private val listImg:ArrayList<Bitmap>,
    private val onClickFunction: ((Int) -> Unit)? = null
):RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerAdapter.MyCustomViewHolder>()
```

Your function takes an integer position, not an Any, and it can't be null.

Your usage of it should go

```
adapter = CustomerAdapter(requireContext(),listImg){ position->

 

    var intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(intent,IMAGE_REQUEST)
}
```

Then you can use position within the function.